# Jenkins docker-plugin - Job does not start (waiting for executor)

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm trying not (not hard enough it seems) to get our jenkins server to provision a jenkins-slave using docker.

I have installed the [Docker-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) and configured it according to the description on the page. I have also tested the connectivity and at least this part works.
I have also configured 1 label in the plugin and in my job. I even get a nice page showing me the connected jobs for this slave.

When I then try to start a build nothing really happens. A build is scheduled, but never started - (pending—Waiting for next available executor).

From the message it would seem like jenkins is not able to start the slave via docker....

I'm using docker 1.6.2 and the plugin is 0.10.1.

Any clue to what is going on would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying not -> I'm trying hard

Comment: In the Jenkins system log I'm seeing this "Bad template 'evarga/jenkins-slave:latest': 'null'" when I start a new build.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that I had added the docker version in the plugin config. That is apparently a no-go according to this [post](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/issues/215)